# Update a field in an array on a Firestore document

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to update a single value in a Firestore document that's in an array? For example, if I have a document like this is there a way to update just the `size` property of the second item?

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "items": [
        {
            "size": 10
        },
        {
            "size": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

I can update a first-level property using the updateData method like this but I'm not sure how I would construct the data to update a value that's in an array.

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"name": @"New Name"};
[documentReference updateData:data completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];
```

Comment: It's not possible with only an update.  You have to read the document, update the array in memory, and update the array field back to the document.

Comment: Ok, I guess one alternative would be to save the array as map with a unique id for each item. I could access them individually like that, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can access map fields by name.